# Convert character-stream to byte-stream and byte-stream to character-stream

Tags: java, filereader, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, filewriter

so I have to convert input character stream to output byte stream and input byte stream to character output stream. I tried something like this:

Character stream to byte stream (I have to use here FileReader and FileOutputStream):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Example
{
    public static void main( String[ ] args ) throws IOException 
    {
        FileReader in = new FileReader( "input.txt" );
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( "test.txt" );
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
        {
           out.write(c);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Byte stream to character stream (I have to use here FileInputStream and FileWriter):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Example
{
    public static void main( String[ ] args ) throws IOException 
    {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream( "input.txt" );
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter( "test.txt" );
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
        {
           out.write(c);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

It's ok or I have something wrong?

Comment: Does it work as expected?

Comment: This will really not do what you think it does; are you aware of character codings?

Comment: You tell us if it's OK: does it work or not, what breaks and when?

Comment: If both files are ".txt" it work's ok. But I didn't tried other types. 
@fge What do you mean by "character codings"?

Comment: @Mateusz every file, whatever its type is, contains bytes. I have the feeling that all you want to do here is to copy a file. The only purpose for which what you're attempting to do would make sense is to change the character encoding of a file. i.e. the way Unicode characters are transformed into bytes in order to be written to a file. For example, read as UTF8 and write as UTF16, or vice-versa. If that's not what you're trying to do, then your question doesn't make much sense, and your code either. You can't just pretend a character is a byte and a byte is a character.

Comment: So, if you want help, please tell us, at a higher level, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

1.You have to use OutputStreamWriter class for converting Character stream to Byte stream.           2.InputStreamReader class for converting Byte stream to Character stream, as these classes are used for  stream conversions between two different streams.

Comment: Along with the  mentioned classes by @Mateusz , using the classes that are mentioned by me above , it is the right way.